# Creating a new column based on condition on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, countif

I am trying to create a column based on a condition in other columns.

There are 5 Individuals Age in a house. I need to count no of individuals in that house by different gender and Age-groups.

Code I have written is not working

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'member':[1,2], 'M1':[20,35],'M2':[27,42], 'M3':[77,62],'M4':[20,0],'M5':[0,35],
                    'G1':['M','F'],'G2':['M','F'],'G3':['M','F'],'G4':['M',0],'G5':[0,'F']})

#CODE WRITTEN
df1['M_20_to_30'] = ((df1[df1.columns[1:5]] >= 20) & (df1[df1.columns[1:5]] <= 30) & (df1[df1.columns[6:10]] == "M")).sum(1)


# EXPECTED OUTPUT
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'member':[1,2], 'M1':[20,35],'M2':[27,42], 'M3':[77,62],'M4':[20,0],'M5':[0,35],
                    'G1':['M','F'],'G2':['M','F'],'G3':['M','F'],'G4':['M',0],'G5':[0,'F'],'M_20_to_30':[2,0]})
```

Comment: You should change `from pandas import DataFrame` to `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: Can you explain the logic? It is easier to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df1['M_20_to_30'] = (df1
                     .iloc[:,df1.columns.str.startswith('M')]
                     .apply(lambda x: sum(x.ge(20) & x.le(30))), 1))

   member  M1  M2  M3  M4  M5 G1 G2 G3 G4 G5  M_20_to_30
0       1  20  27  77  20   0  M  M  M  M  0           3
1       2  35  42  62   0  35  F  F  F  0  F           0
```

Comment: I have got 20 possible columns for age-group and 20 possible columns for gender. filling those columns is based on number of individuals living in that house. those columns are not next to each other. They are far apart. That why I was trying to columns "from" and "to" the condition in the same.

Comment: @SrikanthAyithy not sure if I understand, the expected output matches with yours. the solution only considers the columns starting with `M` irrespective of their position in the dataframe, they can be located anywhere.